# template deduction/substitution fails on smart pointers

Tags: c++, templates, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Let's consider this code:

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
//...
};

struct B : public A<int>
{
//...
};

template<typename T>
bool validate(A<T>* p)
{
    //...
    return true;
};

int main()
{
  A<int>* pA;
  std::cout << validate(pA) << std::endl;

  B* pB;
  std::cout << validate(pB) << std::endl;
}
```

It compiles correctly and works as expected. Now, let's say I'd need to refactor the code to use smart pointers instead, then also `validate` could be changed like this:

```
template<typename T>
bool validate(std::shared_ptr<A<T>> p)
{
    //...
    return true;
};

int main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<A<int>> pA = std::make_shared<A<int>>();
  validate(pA);  //it compiles correctly

  std::shared_ptr<B> pB = std::make_shared<B>();
  validate(pB);  //it FAILS to compile
}
```

You can verify that [here](https://onlinegdb.com/rkKkLLvK8).

What is the reason behind this?

What is the best way to solve this problem without modifying `A` or `B`?

Answer (score 1):

This is because it requires to perform custom casting from `shared_ptr<B>` to `shared_ptr<A<int>>` to disambiguate the template function parameters. Disambiguation of template functions parameters doesn't even attempt to do type casting (aside from some basic stuff).

It is simply not practictical to even try. Well, theoretically there could've been a partial solution that specify which custom castings to try but there isn't. Just use SFINEA and disambiguate it yourself instead of asking compiler to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The ways around this I can see possible are:

Alternative 1)

```
  std::shared_ptr<B> pB = std::make_shared<B>();
  //... do your type B related operations through pB
  validate(std::shared_ptr<A<int>>(pB));
```

Alternative 2)

```
template<typename T>
bool validate(A<T> const & a)
{
    //...
    return true;
}

int main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<A<int>> pA = std::make_shared<A<int>>();
  validate(*pA);

  std::shared_ptr<B> pB = std::make_shared<B>();
  validate(*pB);
}
```

Alternative 3)

```
template<typename T>
bool validate(std::shared_ptr<A<T>> p)
{
    //...
    return true;
}

template<typename T>
bool validate(std::shared_ptr<T> p)
{
    //...
    return true;
}


int main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<A<int>> pA = std::make_shared<A<int>>();
  validate(pA); // it uses bool validate(std::shared_ptr<A<T>> p)

  std::shared_ptr<B> pB = std::make_shared<B>();
  validate(pB); // it uses bool validate(std::shared_ptr<T> p)
}
```

but that implies that the function might extend to many other types, and it is not necessarily a desired behaviour (maybe?).

Any other suggestions guys?
It would be cool if someone knows why the code in the question doesn't work in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In general you should avoid smart pointers if the called function does not change ownership! Use your raw pointer function.

You force a Generic type of `A` in function `validate`. Inheritance is not considered here.

If you ignore inheritance it could look like:

```
template<typename T>
bool validate(std::shared_ptr<T> p)
{
    return true;
}
```

See on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/P_6y3E)

To force a base class I would introduce a Typetag.